# HTML5: Encode 8 bit grayscale JPEG from canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, jpeg, webgl

Is there an easy way to encode 8 bit grayscale JPEG from Canvas using web browser client side technologies (html5/canvas/webgl/javascript)?

Are there any ready-to-use javascript library that I can use without any image-processing knowledge? Browser plugins are not an option except Flash. But I do not prefer Flash if I can.

PLEASE DO NOT RECOMMEND ALGORITHMS OR ANY LINKS THAT HELPS TO IMPLEMENT THAT KIND OF LIBRARY.

Details: Actually, I would like to read a local jpeg image file using HTML5 File API than convert it to 8 bit grayscale jpeg than upload it to the server.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14174105/client-side-conversion-of-rgb-jpg-to-8-bit-jpg-using-canvashtml5

Comment: no, not the same. that question has an answer which says it is possible and link wikipedia pages. But this question wants help about a ready-to-use library or a script which may even include Flash.

Comment: This is a library that helps you with picture manipulation: http://www.pixastic.com/lib/ .  But it won't help you with the compression.

Answer (score 2):

The [alphaJPEG](http://jackadam.github.io/2010/alpha-jpegs/) method uses two images: a normal PNG-24 and a PNG-24 with an alpha channel. It produces an 8-bit JPEG with transparency. Use an [inverse alpha mask](http://kaioa.com/node/104) instead to produce a grayscale 8-bit JPEG.

```
<head>
  <style>img[data-alpha-src]{visibility: hidden;}</style>
</head>
<body>
  <img src="image.jpg" data-alpha-src="alpha.png" />
  <!--...-->
  <script src="ajpeg.js"></script>
</body>
```

ajpeg.js

```
(function() {

  var create_alpha_jpeg = function(img) {

    var alpha_path = img.getAttribute('data-alpha-src')
    if(!alpha_path) return

    // Hide the original un-alpha'd
    img.style.visiblity = 'hidden'

    // Preload the un-alpha'd image
    var image = document.createElement('img')
    image.src = img.src
    image.onload = function () {

      // Then preload alpha mask
      var alpha = document.createElement('img')
      alpha.src = alpha_path
      alpha.onload = function () {

        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
        canvas.width = image.width
        canvas.height = image.height
        img.parentNode.replaceChild(canvas, img)

        // For IE7/8
        if(typeof FlashCanvas != 'undefined') FlashCanvas.initElement(canvas)

        // Canvas compositing code
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d')
        context.clearRect(0, 0, image.width, image.height)
        context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height)
        context.globalCompositeOperation = 'xor'
        context.drawImage(alpha, 0, 0, image.width, image.height)

      }
    }
  }

  // Apply this technique to every image on the page once DOM is ready
  // (I just placed it at the bottom of the page for brevity)
  var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img')
  for(var i = 0; i &lt; imgs.length; i++)
    create_alpha_jpeg(imgs[i])

})();

In the head element I linked to FlashCanvas:

<!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="flashcanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->

... and I threw in this to avoid a flicker of the un-alpha’d JPEG:
```

**References**

- [Emulating Lossy RGBA Images with HTML5's Canvas Element](http://kaioa.com/node/104)
- [Alpha JPEGs](http://jackadam.github.io/2010/alpha-jpegs/)
- [GPU Accelerated Compositing in Chrome](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/gpu-accelerated-compositing-in-chrome)
- [Native One-copy Texture Uploads for Chrome OS](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/native-one-copy-texture-uploads-for-chrome-os-on-intel-architecture-enabled-by-default)

Comment: I don't have or need transparency. and I do not understand how to convert 24 bit jpeg to 8 bit jpeg using this article.